# Ignore folder during Gitlab merge request comparison

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, git-merge

I have 2 branches dev and qa. I have two folders inside the repository 'api' and 'db'.

'db' folder is created just for having a backup. However contents of 'db' folder is different in qa branch as compared with dev branch.

When I raise a merge request from dev into qa, I don't want to see the differences of 'db' folder between dev and qa branch. But differences in 'api' folder needs to e considered and merged.

Can you please suggest how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge from dev into qa without committing. This will allow you to resolve conflicts and make any necessary adjustments before the actual merge commit.

```
git checkout qa
git pull
git merge dev --no-commit --no-ff
```

Then, reset the db folder. By resetting the db folder, you're essentially discarding changes from the dev branch for this folder and keeping it the way it is on the qa branch.

```
git reset HEAD db/
git checkout -- db/
```

Commit and push the changes.

```
git commit -m "Merged changes from dev into qa excluding db folder."
git push
```

The differences in the db folder weren't included in the merge in this case.